# Trouble rendering to multiple cube maps

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping, shadow-mapping

I'm trying to implement shadow mapping to a scene with many light sources. I've successfully managed to render to a cube map and use the resulting texture to detect the shadows.

However, when trying to make a second cube map texture, I lose  my first texture . After some debugging I realized that the first texture is destroyed when the second binding command is executed:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_EXT, cubeMap[i]);
```

As soon as this command executes for i=1 I lose the texture cubeMap[0].

I will upload more lines of code if necessary but as I've found the specific line causing the problem I think it might be enough. Please let me know otherwise.

I'm using render doc and I can see the first texture on texture viewer as long as the line above doesn't execute. If I execute the whole second loop I am able to see only the texture cubeMap[1]. I'm generally able to see only the last bound cube map texture.

Comment: You can bind textures to different texture units. See [`glActiveTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you. It did solve my problem but why is it necessary here? Recently I followed exactly the same process using multiple 2D textures and I didn't have to bind to different texture units to create all of them.